# Decoding a recursive multiway tree

Tags: json, elm, multiway-tree

I'm working on a recursive tree of this type

```
type Node anyType
  = Leaf Id (Maybe anyType) Name
  | Tree Id (List (Node anyType)) Name
```

where

```
type Id
  = Id Int
  | Root
```

and I'm trying to decode a json of this kind into it

```
{
  "id": "root",
  "entries": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": 0,
      "name": "New Entry"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "entries": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "value": 0,
          "name": "New Entry"
        }
      ],
      "name": "New Entry"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Budget"
}
```

To decode the Id type I'm using these decoders

```
rootDecoder =
(Decode.field "id" Decode.string)
    |> Decode.andThen
        (\str ->
            if str == "root" then
                (Decode.succeed Root)

            else
                Decode.fail <| "[exactMatch] tgt: " ++ "root" ++ " /= " ++ str
        )


intIdDecoder =
    Decode.map Id (Decode.field "id" Decode.int)


idDecoder =
    Decode.oneOf
        [ rootDecoder
        , intIdDecoder
        ]
```

To decode the tree structure i tried the following, using Json.Decode.Pipeline:

```
leafDecoder valueDecoder =
    Decode.succeed Leaf
        |> required "id" idDecoder
        |> required "value" valueDecoder
        |> required "name" Decode.string


treeDecoder valueDecoder =
    Decode.succeed Tree
        |> required "id" idDecoder
        |> required "entries"
            (Decode.list
                (Decode.lazy
                    (\_ ->
                        Decode.oneOf
                            [ leafDecoder valueDecoder
                            , treeDecoder valueDecoder
                            ]
                    )
                )
            )
        |> required "name" Decode.string
```

But when I try to decode the structure I get the following error:

```
The Json.Decode.oneOf at json.budget.entries[0] failed in the following 2 ways: (1) The Json.Decode.oneOf at json.id failed in the following 2 ways: (1) Problem with the given value: 1 Expecting an OBJECT with a field named `id` (2) Problem with the given value: 1 Expecting an OBJECT with a field named `id` (2) Problem with the given value: { "id": 1, "value": 0, "name": "New Entry" } Expecting an OBJECT with a field named `entries`
```

But I don't understand why since both the field `id` and `entries` are there, and yet it complains.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `leafDecoder` and `treeDecoder` you have the following lines:

```
leafDecoder valueDecoder =
    Decode.succeed Leaf
        |> required "id" idDecoder
        -- rest of function omitted...

treeDecoder valueDecoder =
    Decode.succeed Tree
        |> required "id" idDecoder
        -- rest of function omitted...
```

These will both pull out the value of the field `id` within the current object and pass this value on to `idDecoder`, which calls `Decode.oneOf` with `rootDecoder` and `intIdDecoder`.

However, in your `rootDecoder` and `intIdDecoder` you have the following:

```
rootDecoder =
    (Decode.field "id" Decode.string)
        |> Decode.andThen
            -- rest of function omitted...

intIdDecoder =
    Decode.map Id (Decode.field "id" Decode.int)
```

These decoders attempt to pull the value of a field named `id` from the current object. But you pass these functions the value of the `id` property, not an object containing this property.

These decoders would work if your `id`s were nested in objects that only contained `id` properties, for example:

```json
{
  "id": {"id": "root"},
  "entries": [
    {
      "id": {"id": 1},
      "value": 0,
      "name": "New Entry"
    },
    ...
```

The fix is to remove the calls to `Decode.field` in `rootDecoder` and `intIdDecoder`, as these decoders already get passed the value of the `id` field:

```
rootDecoder =
    Decode.string
        |> Decode.andThen
            -- rest of function as before, and omitted for brevity...


intIdDecoder =
    Decode.map Id Decode.int
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that both `rootDecoder` and `intIdDecoder` are defined as looking for a field named `"id"` in an object via `Decode.field "id" ...`. Inside `treeDecoder`, you are first fetching the `"id"` field, so your decoder is valid for some JSON like this

```json
// Not what you're looking for
{
  "id": {
    "id": ...
  },
  ...
}
```

You can fix this by removing the `Decode.field "id"` portion in those decoders:

```
rootDecoder = Decode.string
    |> Decode.andThen
        (\str ->
            if str == "root" then
                (Decode.succeed Root)

            else
                Decode.fail <| "[exactMatch] tgt: " ++ "root" ++ " /= " ++ str
        )


intIdDecoder =
    Decode.map Id Decode.int
```